# in over multiple lists

Tags: python, syntax, operator-precedence

I was recently confused by this

```py
if 2 in ([1,2] or [3,4]) : print(True)
else: print(False)
#prints True
```

1. `or` is a boolean operator so how can it be applied to lists?
2. why does it work the same as `if 2 in [1,2] or [3,4]`?

Comment: That condition should actually read `if any(2 in sub for sub in [[1,2], [3,4]]):`

Comment: To answer your other question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39983695/what-is-truthy-and-falsy-how-is-it-different-from-true-and-false a non-empty list is considered "truthy" so `[1,2] or [3,4]` evaluates to `True`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Use `any()`

```
print(any(2 in x for x in [[1, 2], [3, 4]]))
```

2. `or` is operates on any types, not just booleans. It returns the leftmost operand that's truthy, or `False` if none of the operands are truthy. So `([1, 2] or [3, 4])` is equivalent to `[1, 2]` because any non-empty list is truthy.

In general, operators don't automatically distribute in programming languages like they do in English. `x in (a or b)` is not the same as `x in a or x in b`. Programming languages evaluate expressions recursively, so `x in (a or b)` is roughly equivalent to:

```
temp = a or b
x in temp
```

Answer (score 1):

- Both statement are different.
- In first case python will first run `2 in [1,4]` its `False` so now it will check for `bool([1,3])` and its `True` so it prints 1.
- But for second case what happening is first `([1,4] or [1,3])` is executing and this return first non-empty list. And so it will return `[1,4]` but 2 is not in list so nothing gets printed.
- Its all about execution order.
- Look at two more examples. Specially last example. `([1,4] or [2,4])` will return `[1,4]` and 2 is not in `[1,4]`. Now it will not check in second list `[2,4]`. If that's you want this is not the right way to do it. Use `any`

```py
>>> if 2 in [1,4] or [1,3]: # True
...     print(1)
...
1
>>> if 2 in ([1,4] or [1,3]): # False
...     print(1)
...
>>> if 2 in [1,4] or []: # False
...     print(1)
...
>>> if 2 in ([1,4] or [2,4]): # False!!
...     print(1)
...
```

Comment: @lineage updated